# Gauss's law giving incorrect answer

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

Let's consider two concentric spherical shells, one of radius $R$ and one of radius $R - \Delta R$. The outer shell is negatively charged and the inner shell positively, but both the shells have net charges -Q and Q respectively. This means that the inner shell, having a smaller radius, has a higher surface charge density.

Now, according to shell theorem (i.e., direct integration), the electric field for at any $r>R$ will be equal and opposite for the two shells and hence cancel out.

But if we make a circular gaussian pill box, whose cross-sectional area $\Delta A$ is diminishingly small, and whose one end is outside both the shells, and the other inside both, then this will gives us that:

$$E_{outside} = \frac {\rho_-} {\epsilon_0} + \frac {\rho_+} {\epsilon_0}$$

since the sides do not contribute any flux, and the inner side, being inside both the shells, gives $E = 0$ from shell theorem.

Since $\rho_+$ depends on $\Delta R$, hence $E = E(\Delta R)$.

This is an absurd contradiction between the answers obtained from the two methods. What am I doing wrong here?

$\bf{UPDATE:}$

Moderator $\bf{dmckee}$ has answered the question in one of his comments:

"since the sides do not contribute any flux" Er ... unless you are making a conic pill-box they do, albeit not much if the shell is thin compared to it's own radius. However, it's enough.

Comment: *"since the sides do not contribute any flux"* Er ... unless you are making a *conic* pill-box they do, albeit not much if the shell is thin compared to it's own radius. However, it's enough.

Comment: @dmckee: You can paste your comment in the answer box, and delete the comment. I will accept your answer.